# How to make a foreign key relationship to a many-to-many field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the following models:

```
class Work_Music(MPTTModel, Work):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

class Opera(models.Model):
    work = models.OneToOneField(Work_Music, verbose_name=_('work_music'), related_name='opera', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    cast = models.ManyToManyField('Cast', through='WorkCast')
    source_writer = models.ForeignKey(Person, verbose_name=_('author'), null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    numbering = models.CharField(max_length=8000, null=True, blank=True)
    work_type = models.CharField(max_length=8000, null=True, blank=True)

class Cast(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class WorkCast(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work_Music, verbose_name=_('work'), related_name='workcast', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    cast = models.ManyToManyField(Cast, verbose_name=_('cast'), related_name='workcast', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (
            ", ".join(character.name for character in self.cast.all())
        )
```

Currently the data structure is:

```
WorkCast
   |-----> Opera
   |-----> Opera cast member #1
           Opera cast member #2
           Opera cast member #3
```

I would now like to attach a sing range to each cast member for this particular piece of work. Some thing like:

```
WorkCast
   |-----> (ForeignKey)   Opera
   |-----> (Many-to-many) Opera cast member #1, lowest note: c, highest note: A#
                          Opera cast member #2, lowest note: b, highest note: D
                          Opera cast member #3, lowest note: a, highest note: E
```

How can I attached:

```
lowest_note = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
highest_note = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

for each cast member for this particular piece?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `through table`. Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Your code would look something like this.

```
class WorkCast(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work_Music, verbose_name=_('work'), related_name='workcast', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    cast = models.ManyToManyField(Cast, verbose_name=_('cast'), related_name='workcast', blank=True, through='SingRange')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (
            ", ".join(character.name for character in self.cast.all())
        )

class SingRange(models.Model):
    lowest_note = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    highest_note = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The modeling is a bit "*odd*". Normally, one would expect that you define the `ManyToManyField` on the `WorkMusic` model, and use your `WorkCast` as the "through" model in between. You specify this with the [**`through=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through). Like:

```
class WorkMusic(MPTTModel, Work):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    cast = models.ManyToManyField('Cast', through='WorkCast')


class Cast(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class WorkCast(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(
        WorkMusic,
        verbose_name=_('work'),
        related_name='workcast',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    cast = models.ForeignKey(
        Cast,
        verbose_name=_('cast'),
        related_name='workcast',
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    lowest_note = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    highest_note = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

Here we thus will encode for every `WorkCast` object, which is related to *one* `WorkMusic` object, and *one* `Cast` object the extra fields. A `WorkMusic` object can however have *zero, one, or more* related `WorkCast` objects, and thus is related to *zero, one, or more* `Cast` objects.

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `WorkMusic` instead of <s>`Work_Music`</s>.

Comment: I slightly simplified my model to ask the question, but I'm getting errors so I'm amending my original question a bit and hope you can help. I have a opera model that is attached to WorkMusic.  This is because not all works are opera and I only wanted to attached the relativist metadata to those that are opera. Is this still the correct modeling? I'm getting this error. art_perf.WorkCast: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'art_perf.Opera.cast', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Opera' or 'Cast'.

Comment: And how do you add this to admin.py to add the data?

Comment: @HC: did you add the two `ForeignKey`s to your `Cast` and `Opera`, like in the answer?

Comment: Ok. I see the problem. I made the attachments to the opera model. Right now, the runtime has significant slowed down.  Separately, is there a way to structure admin.py, such that in Workcast, I can select multiple cast members at the same time and assign highest and lowest note range all at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own model for m2m relationship and add all necessary fields to this model. You can use this model in `ManyToManyField` specifying through argument.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships